# Glob with flutter web

Tags: flutter, glob

do you know an equivalent to the lib "Glob" for flutter web please ?

Glob flutter lib
A library to perform Bash-style file and directory globbing.
https://pub.dev/packages/glob

Thx

Comment: But what do you want to use glob on? Internet browsers don't have a _simple_ access to the filesystem. What do you need it for?

Comment: I would like to upload folders with associated files. if folders contains .gitignore file, i would like to analyze pattern inside et exclude files corresponding to gitignore patterns.